# acts_as_taggable_on finding in batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find, batch-processing, acts-as-taggable-on

Using acts_as_taggable_on to find a models instances with certain tags is done by something like this:

```
Ninja.tagged_with(["invincibility,uber-strength", any: true)
```

However, what if I have 2million ninjas in my ninja directory and want to run a job on many of them.

I could find in batches but I don't quite understand how to do this with tags on a model.  For example:

```
Ninja.all.find_in_batches(batch_size:1000) do |group|
  group.each do |ninja|
    ninja.battle!
  end
end
```

Is there a way to batch the tagged with query?

Comment: I can append but i'm wondering if the damage is already done.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so tagged_with seems to return an ActiveRecord Relation so I assume find_in_batches should work as desired appended tagged_with.